# Unexpected behaviour with React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs

```
myVar = this.state.value;
console.log(myVar); //some string e.g "my string"
console.log(typeof myVar); // string 
var test = " string part";
passString = test + myVar;
console.log(passString); //string part my string 
clonedChild = React.cloneElement(child, {newProp: myVar})
```

On the cloned child I see newProp but it is "string partnull"

It nust be some kind of scoping issue...

UPDATE:

Here is the actual JavaScript code;

```
(configDataX = this.state, console.log("In App Component. Rendering with state", configDataX), newChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (function(_this) {
            return function(child) {
              return React.cloneElement(child, {
                foobx: true,
                appData: configDataX
              });
            };
})(this))));
```

this is kicked off by a fluxxor emit("change") event.  This is raised in the successful callback from an Ajax request.  The StoreWatchMixin correctly hears this event and sets the obtained values onto the component's state.  State changes and the render happens. The above code is in a render() method. The console.log of configDataX shows that we have obtained the values from the Ajax call and set them onto state. Debugging into the map function configDataX is still correct. But the value which ends up on the cloned child is not the one that was set in the Ajax request - it is the one set into the store before the Ajax request.

It is like the state values being used are ones from before the Ajax request. Have I perhaps used that state in a closure? But why then when I debug it do I see the values from after the Ajax request on configDataX?

I am at a complete loss.

Comment: *"On the cloned child I see newProp but it is null."* ... *"However I can pass a string"* So, most likely `this.state.value` is `null`.

Comment: Maybe. But the strange thing is I can see it. I've edited my question to show in more detail what happens

Comment: With the code above the newProp could never have "string part"  in it. But maybe it works as intended if you change first line to: `var myVar = ""+this.state.value` ?